# How what Lea said is not hutzpo

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sexuality, vayeitzei, imahot-matriarch-mothers

I know that a wife can not demand relations (maybe only is using speech) and if she does it is bad for the children, from that relationship, so the husband should not do it. See "brazen woman" [here](http://halakhah.com/nedarim/nedarim_20.html)   and audio 13:08 [here](http://download.dafyomi.org/content/dafyomi/mp3/nedarim/nedarim_020b.mp3),  [here](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/ShasBavli.aspx?English=True&PageNum=1045&ShiurLang=English) you can choose other people reading it.

Why what Lea said is not this? (or if it is why is it permitted for her to say and for Abraham to do?).
Did Yesohor get effected by her actions?

["You are to sleep with me, for I have hired you with my son’s mandrakes"](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.30.16.)

Comment: That is not a precise translation of what she said...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Nedarim 20b with Rashi](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B_%D7%91) (end of the Perek) as well as [Eiruvin 100b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A7_%D7%91) that addresses this question and makes it clear that she did not actually demand it by mouth but rather she hinted it to him.
Also, note that the Gemara says that this was a tremendous Zechus for Yessachar that helped him become the great person he was.

Comment: @DoubleAA another view ויש שכתבו שאכן לאה תבעה בפה, אלא כוונתה היתה לשם מצווה, וכ"כ היראים (מובא בשטמ"ק נדרים כ, ב): "אבל תובעת בפה להשביע יצרה הואי חצופה, ולאה – לטובה נתכוונה". בדומה לזה כתב תורת חיים (עירובין שם): "אף על גב דלאה תבעה בפה, לשם שמים נתכוונה להרבות שבטים, ולפי שמשכב אותו הלילה של רחל היה, הוצרכה לאה להודיעו בפיה. ומכל מקום כיון שזכתה בכך שיצא ממנה יששכר, שמעינן מינה דכל אשה שתובעת בעלה לדבר מצוה בדרך המותר לה, כגון דארצויי קמיה – הוויין לה בנים דאפילו בדורו של משה כו'". וכך נראה מתוס' סוטה כב, א, 'כל'. (עיין לקמן יג, יא, בביאור בני חצופה). http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/14-02-06/